# Create secure websocket server in local machine

Tags: c#, websocket, progressive-web-apps, websocket-sharp

I'm trying to use a local websocket server in order to communicate between PWA and windows app.
My problem is that pwa requires secure connections and it won't work with a regular websocket server.

So my problem is mainly.
How do I certificate my machine so it can be used with pwa?

I'm using websocket sharp to create websocket server and I don't know how to initialize it as secure server

Answer (score 0):

Try make the websocket server listen on loopback ip `127.0.0.1` (not localhost) and a free port, I recently made a desktop application that runs SuperSocket server and it works fine with Https frontend.

Loopback is considered secure, but not localhost.

Example request: `ws://127.0.0.1:8001`